# What does "word count" refer to when calculating unigram probabilities in an unigram language model?

Tags: nlp

I'm using an unigram language model. I want to calculate the probability of each unigram. Should I divide the number of occurrences of an unigram with the number of distinct unigrams, or by the count of all unigrams?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Divide by the total number of [*tokens*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type%E2%80%93token_distinction), i.e. word occurrences, in the training set. The reason is quite easy to see: if you divide by the number of distinct words, the probabilities for all words will not necessarily sum to one so they won't form a probability distribution.

Comment: Actually if it's divided by the number of distinct words, the probability for one single item alone can even exceed 100%......

Answer (score 2):

A good intro read about language modelling are Jurafsky's slides:
http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs124/lec/languagemodeling.pdf

Answer (score 1):

I reference the [PDF](http://www.phontron.com/slides/nlp-programming-en-01-unigramlm.pdf) from Nara Institute of Science and Technology, but slightly modify its example with the start tokens.

The example would be self-explanatory.

```
<s> i live in osaka . </s> 
<s> i am a graduate student . </s>
<s> my school is in nara . </s>
```

The total number of tokens is 23, including the `<s>`, `</s>`, and `.`.

What is the `p(<s> i live in nara . </s>)`?

```
p(<s>) = 3/23
p(i) = 2/23
p(live) = 1/23
p(in) = 2/23
p(nara) = 1/23
p(.) = 3/23
p(</s>) = 3/23
```

The `p(<s> i live in nara . </s>)` would be

```
(3/23)*(2/23)*(1/23)*(2/23)*(1/23)*(3/23)*(3/23) = (108)*(1/23)^7
```